# Soap client is throwing exception while calling WCF service "A connection attempt failed"

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, soap-client

I am trying to call a wcf service using SoapClient.
This is working fine on deployed environment, but while calling from local it is throwing below exception:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:443
```

Inner exception:

```
There was no endpoint listening at https://XXX/service.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
```

I am using below code to call my service:

```
    var client = new ServiceSoapClient();  
              
                try 
                { 
                    client.Open(); 
                    result = client.AllocateAddress( 
                        _companyName, 
                        _password, 
                        address.Street,  
                        address.Zip, 
                        lob, 
                        policyEffectiveDate.ToShortDateString());
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the asmx service on production allow access only to specific ip address ? which is not your dev machine ip address.

Comment: The inner exception is pretty clear, I think.   Do you have the correct address?  Can you browse to the service in a browser?

Comment: Thank you @Tim. service is not accessible from browser itself. It might not having rights to access from all the IP addresses.